# elasticsearch 's POC for DWH visualization

Tags: json, elasticsearch, bigdata, kibana, elastic-stack

I am just exploring  ELK stack, we are looking to use elastic search for our DWH analytics and visulaization.
one scenario I am unable to figure is , how to keep our existing data  which is in warehouse to transform in to documents.

e.g.

our transnational  data includes  device_ids  with their  respective  states,  we  have   30000 ids(approx)  per  day in terms of states. like
"Transaction Table T1"
columns: Date,Device_id,type,alarm1,state,comments

"lookup table" T2
column:device_id,user_id

those 30000 plus device_id   are mapped with 5000(approx) users, on the basis they can see their respective device status.

Problem is if I de normalize this structure  in elastic search  then I will endup having    30000*5000 = 150 million  documents per day  which is not the way to go for sure.

As in RDBMS  you keep normalize structure to minimize data size and loading efficiency , what would we can model this data in elastic search  so  as  keeping  user based  access  intact  on  final output  in kibana.  I am not familiar how to model in  elastic search.

Appreciate your advice on this.

Comment: Why put user in the device documents (30k / days) or devices data in the users (5K / days) ?

Comment: we  are looking to connect ELK stack with our DB2  wherehouse and perform analysis. 
In my above example: I mentioned two tables    
Table1 contains device info  updated daily (30 K devices daily).
Table 2(lookup table)  have users mapping to those devices.

My question is how to move this data  relations  into elasticsearch.

Comment: According to how you need to use your data (by data ? by device? by users) and how many connection exists between the 2 table you could make 1 document by device, and inside of it nested documents (if needed, or just an array) of how users use these devices. If you prefer to work by users of course, could be better to make 1 document by users with devices on it. You could create a new index each day / week / month to control the index size.